# Warnings/errors referenced by EventLogs not appearing in Driver/Worker logs

Tags: logging, apache-spark

We are experiencing tasks being killed apparently due to rpc issues.

Here is the error - as extracted from the JSON record:

```
Executor heartbeat timed out after 122312 ms"
```

Furthermore there is a reference to the "driver logs" for more info:

```
"Removed Reason": "Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to 
 containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. 
 Check driver logs for WARN messages
```

Note in particular that last line: ***Check driver logs for WARN messages***

Here are the actual JSON records:

```
{
    "Event": "SparkListenerTaskEnd",
    "Stage ID": 0,
    "Stage Attempt ID": 0,
    "Task Type": "ShuffleMapTask",
    "Task End Reason": {
        "Reason": "ExecutorLostFailure",
        "Executor ID": "0",
        "Exit Caused By App": true,
        "Loss Reason": "Executor heartbeat timed out after 122312 ms"
    },
    "Task Info": {
        "Task ID": 1,
        "Index": 1,
        "Attempt": 0,
        "Launch Time": 1481563127396,
        "Executor ID": "0",
        "Host": "192.168.0.11",
        "Locality": "PROCESS_LOCAL",
        "Speculative": false,
        "Getting Result Time": 0,
        "Finish Time": 1481563369233,
        "Failed": true,
        "Accumulables": []
    }
} {
    "Event": "SparkListenerBlockManagerRemoved",
    "Block Manager ID": {
        "Executor ID": "0",
        "Host": "192.168.0.11",
        "Port": 39215
    },
    "Timestamp": 1481563369238
} {
    "Event": "SparkListenerExecutorRemoved",
    "Timestamp": 1481563370607,
    "Executor ID": "0",
    "Removed Reason": "Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages."
}
```

However ***no mention was found in the Driver or Worker logs*** either warnings or errors.

There is a possibly related item:  ***stdout and stderr are always empty*** .  I do see messages on the driver console - but nothing in the logs.

Any pointers appreciated.